# Delete DataGridViewRow based on cell content

Tags: c#

This has been giving me a headache for the past hour. I want to delete a datagridView row based on if a specific cell matches the input data. And shift all the other rows beneath it up (thought this may automatically be done I don't know, I just don't want any blank rows).

This is what I have so far however I get "object reference not set to an instance of an object" error occurring on "dataGridView1.SelectedRows":

```
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
{
    if (row.Cells[0].ToString() == "test")
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(row);
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `if (row.Cells[0].Value.ToString() == "test")`

Comment: the UI is not the right place to put your business logic. You should read up on the MVC/MVP patterns or use current technology (WPF) and the MVVM pattern. the `DataGridView` and it's UI-related children elements have nothing to do with removing a **Data** record from a Data-related record collection.

Comment: This may work, though it still doesn't get me past the error which occurs.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean @HighCore I just want to remove a row from the dataGridView, nothing else.

Comment: @user3537381 What I mean is that you should create a proper strongly typed data model and base your business logic off of that instead of relying on highly error-prone, magic-string-based, untyped stuff such as `row.Cells[0].ToString()` type of stuff. What happens if someone adds a new column at position 0 in your grid? Your code will stop working. See how your approach is highly unmaintainable and doesn't scale because your code is too tightly coupled to the UI? You should learn programming good practices and forget winforms.

Comment: @HighCore I see what you're saying, though this was just my feeble attempt at getting it to work, it doesn't so this is an incorrect method. However the user cannot directly add rows anyway, they are added indirectly via other code which determines its string value. What I want to do is when a piece of data has no use anymore it just deletes from the datagridview1, I am new to c#, forgive me. Is there any other way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
     {
         dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(item.Index);
     }
```

Comment: `this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows` == `dataGridView1.SelectedRows`

Comment: I still get "object reference not set to an instance of an object" on "this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows".

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I just get that error on runtime.

Comment: you delete row on button click..?

Comment: oh, I'm deleting the row when  the user has no use for it. "In a constructor called from another object"

Comment: em, that if statement is exactly the same thing as I posted in the op. And it doesn't work

Comment: in your code foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
{
    if (row.Cells[0].ToString() == "test")
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(row);
    }
}
remove method parameter is row please replace this row to row.index

Comment: The if statement isn't creating the error, it is the foreach statement. At this moment the if statement is unreachable due to this error crashing the program.

Answer (score 0):

What about a nice extension method?

```
dataGridView1.TrimByCellValue( "targetvalue" );
```

Copy code into DataGridViewExtensions.cs

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

public static class DataGridViewExtensions
{
    public static void TrimByCellValue(this DataGridView grid, string deleteme)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("DataGridViewExtensions->Trim()");
        foreach (DataGridViewRow _row in grid.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewCell _cell in _row.Cells)
            {
                if ((_cell.Value != null) && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_cell.Value.ToString())))
                {
                    if ( _cell.Value.ToString().CompareTo(deleteme) == 0 )
                            grid.Rows.Remove(_row);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```